# Disable Trackpad and Keyboard Temporarily

Tags: keyboard, mouse

Is it possible to disable the trackpad and mouse temporarily while you have an external mouse and keyboard plugged in.

The keys keep getting accidentally hit while I have the mouse and keyboard plugged in. 

**Edit**

Thank you to everyone who answered, because of this I was able to make an applescript to toggle the builtin keyboard on and off:

```
try
    if (display dialog "Press OK to Enable Keyboard and cancel to disable.") = {button returned:"OK"} then
        do shell script "sudo kextload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleUSBTopCase.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleUSBTCKeyboard.kext/" with administrator privileges
    end if
on error msg
    do shell script "sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleUSBTopCase.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleUSBTCKeyboard.kext/" with administrator privileges
end try
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before doing this.....

WARNING: Before disabling the built-in keyboard, make darn sure you have an external keyboard connected!!

WARNING: Before disabling the built-in trackpad, make sure you have an external mouse connected!

```
 sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleUSBTopCase.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleUSBTCKeyboard.kext/
```

To enable it use external keyboard...

```
sudo kextload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleUSBTopCase.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleUSBTCKeyboard.kext/
```

Source: http://t3chnot3s.blogspot.com/2013/12/disabling-built-in-keyboard-and.html

However I would recommend a simple and safe and very temporary method is to cut a piece of cardboard and place it on top of the keyboard. It worked for me to prevent my Cat taking over.

Comment: Is there any way to allow a reboot to effectively reverse this?  Also what about the touchpad?  I believe because it is a kext it is reversed on reboot.

Comment: Also for whatever reason I have to run this twice often oh well.

Answer (score 3):

For the trackpad, there’s a setting for this on 10.7 and later.

System Preferences > Accessibility > Mouse & Trackpad > “Ignore built-in trackpad when mouse or wireless trackpad is present”

As for the keyboard: I haven’t tested [this solution for disabling the built-in keyboard](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=433407) and wouldn’t recommend doing it either. Apparently you can unload a kernel extension to disable it completely.

Comment: I also saw that and didn't suggest it because of it could cause issues.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to disable the built-in trackpad using a keyboard shortcut, make a new Automator service and add this Applescript:

```
global state
set startTime to do shell script "perl -e 'use Time::HiRes qw(time); print time'"
if running of application "System Preferences" then
    quit application "System Preferences"
    delay 0.05
end if
tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal pane id "com.apple.preference.universalaccess"
    delay 0.05
    tell application "System Events"
        tell window 1 of application process "System Preferences"
            select table 1 of scroll area 1
            select row 15 of table 1 of scroll area 1
            tell checkbox 2 of tab group 1 of group 1
                click
                set state to item (((get value of attribute "AXValue") as integer) + 1) of {"Enabled", "Disabled"}
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
    quit
end tell
set endTime to do shell script "perl -e 'use Time::HiRes qw(time); print time'"
set elapsed to (round ((endTime - startTime) * 1000 * 1000)) / 1000
display notification (elapsed as string) & "ms" with title state & " Built-In Trackpad" subtitle "Time taken:"
```

Then go to System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services and assign a keyboard shortcut to your service.

Answer (score 1):

Cannot find out how to do disable the keyboard but to disable the trackpad do this (for Yosemite)

Go to `System Preferences > Accessibility > Mouse & Trackpad` and check `Ignore built-in trackpad when mouse or wireless trackpad is present`

Got this from [here](http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/disable-macbook-trackpad/).

If you don't want to use the keyboard don't touch it! Will look this up if you still want to know.

Comment: Thank you for the response I believe the keyboard response is slightly more valuable at this time

Comment: Thats ok. How do you accidentally press a key on the keyboard?

Comment: my cat sometimes presses the buttons