# MacBook Pro clicking wont work!

Tags: macbook-pro

I have a 2011 13" MacBook Pro. It has had no problems up until now. Suddenly, clicking won't work! I thought that it was the touchpad that wasn't working right, but then I connected a mouse and the problem still persists! Sometimes it doesn't want to click, and other times it won't stop clicking. I have gone online and tried everything that people have recommended but nothing works!

Comment: You may want to include links to solutions you've tried.

Comment: To be sure it's not a hardware issue, you could disable the trackpad while you have an a external mouse connected. There are instructions in this answer: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/177148/38539

Comment: The trackpad may be stuck, so the mouse clicks register but does not change anything.

Answer (score 8):

To restore some functionality, go to System Preferences > Trackpad, and tick the box next to "Tap to click".

[image]

It's possible this is a software or driver issue. However:

If the trackpad does not depress with a "click-clack" noise when you push the lower left or right corner, it's possible you have a hardware issue: Something is preventing it from moving internally. On a 2011 MacBook Pro this can be caused by:

• Battery swelling
• Improperly adjusted Trackpad screw (movement over time can cause the screw to rotate)
• Trackpad hardware failure

To diagnose the cause, inspect the bottom case of your MacBook Pro. Is the case swollen under the trackpad, either visibly or by touch? If so, your battery should be replaced immediately.

If the trackpad doesn't depress when pushed, it's most likely a stuck trackpad (screw adjustment) or a trackpad hardware failure.

Repairing Disk Permissions can sometimes solve input issues.

Go to Applications > Utilities > launch Disk Utility. From the First Aid tab, select your Hard Drive in the left field, then click the Verify Disk Permissions button. If you find errors, you will need to restart to repair them.

Restart while holding down CMD + R, select Disk Utilities from the menu (if you aren't there already), select your Hard Drive from the left hand field, and then click Repair Disk Permissions.

You can also try resetting the System Management Controller (SMC), by using the procedure here:

(From Link Below):
• Portable Macs with non-removable batteries: Make sure the Mac is plugged in to AC power. On the built-in keyboard, press and hold the Shift, Option, and Control keys on the left side and press the power button. Release all the keys at once, and then turn the Mac on normally.

• Portable Macs with removable batteries: Disconnect the AC power cord and remove the battery. Press the power button, hold it for 5 seconds, and then let go. Put the battery back in, reconnect the power cord, and turn the Mac on normally.

http://www.macworld.com/article/2881177/how-to-reset-your-macs-nvram-pram-and-smc.html

Comment: The touchpad clicks and makes the sound that you say, and because it also doesnt work wirh any mouse i plug in, i dont think its a problem with thw hardware. i also already tried the option you suggested. :/

Comment: @ultrabytes Added some options

Comment: Just had this issue (trackpad on my 2011 Macbook Air wouldn't depress in the bottom left corner) - this was caused by one of the battery cells swelling.  Around the same time, my mac warned me that the battery required a service.  Fixed the issue by replacing the battery with a 3rd party one from eBay - problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try resetting the System Management Controller (SMC), by using the procedure here:

(From http://www.macworld.com/article/2881177/how-to-reset-your-macs-nvram-pram-and-smc.html)

**Portable Macs with non-removable batteries:**

1. Make sure the Mac is plugged in to AC power.
2. On the built-in keyboard, press and hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Option</kbd> and <kbd>Control</kbd> keys on the left side and then press the power button.
3. Release all the keys at once, and then turn the Mac on normally.

**Portable Macs with removable batteries:**

1. Disconnect the AC power cord and remove the battery.
2. Press and hold the power button down for 5 seconds
3. Put the battery back in
4. Reconnect the power cord, and turn the Mac on normally.

***The above procedure worked for me***

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround, for the 2016 MacBook Pro:

**System Preferences** → **Trackpad** → **Point & Click** → toggle **Force Click and haptic feedback** (switch it off, then back on again).

[image: System Preferences → Trackpad]

(If necessary, use an external mouse to do this).

When I experienced this, it definitely wasn't a hardware issue, because it was still producing haptic feedback on click. Also, it would still register right-click events (two fingers) and force-click events.

Answer (score 0):

Also for the 2016 Macbook Pro, this will happen frequently when the magic mouse II and the peripheral trackpad are simultaneously connected - happens to me all of the time. 
Switching the mouse off returns the built-in trackpad to normal. HTH.
It just doesn't seem to like the trio of peripheral trackpad, in-built track-pad and magic mouse all connected at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

**IF NONE OF THAT WORKS**

BUT and you can STILL scroll and move around, possibly even hard click twice which will pull up the dictionary..but still can not "CLICK" with your trackpad

**MAKE SURE your BLUETOOTH MOUSE (aka Magic Mouse) is NOT ON..... and no USB mouse is plugged in**

The Magic Mouse was my issue, I accidentally turned it on while rummaging through my laptop bag.  I tried all the methods here and more...

NOTE: SOME would seem to work momentarily because after a restart or lid close/open/sleep, the computer took a second to reconnect to the hidden mouse. Until it re-connected...the trackpad would click.

If that is not your problem, to ease your pain,

**use these commands below to navigate and save your work before you do any of the force restart/smc methods etc**

**Note: HOLD COMMAND KEY *then* HIT THE SECOND KEY**

- Command Tab (to move between programs, hit tab again to move to next prog.)
- Command ~ (to move between windows of a program, ~ is between esc + tab keys.
- Command S (to save your work since you need to restart)
- Command q (to close individual programs)
- Command w (to close a single window in a program, one document, one webpage)
- Command n (to open a new web browser that will allow you to type in another question without clicking the search bar
- Command t will also work by opening a new tab in your browser which puts your cursor in the search bar. Hit enter when done searching.
- Use TAB to go between search results, enter to pick one, and if you go too far press Shift Tab to go in reverse.